# difficult python curve_fit multi-dimensional task requiring an optional argument

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a set of data made up of (2-dimensional) observations of multiple objects. The observations can be described by a general function plus an offset that is unique to each object. I want to use curve_fit to simultaneously recover the general function and the offsets for each object (with associated errors). I do not know in advance how many objects the data-set will be made up of, only that there are likely to be multiple observations of each.

So a generalised data set of 7 observations might look like this:

```
[[x[0], y1[0], y2[0], lab='A'], 
[x[1], y1[1], y2[1], lab='B'],
[x[2], y1[2], y2[2], lab='A'],
[x[3], y1[3], y2[3], lab='A'],
[x[4], y1[4], y2[4], lab='B'],
[x[5], y1[5], y2[5], lab='C'],
[x[6], y1[6], y2[6], lab='A']]
```

I could do the task by passing the parameters of the general function (say g = [g0, g1, g2]) and the object offsets offsets = n x [o1, o2] to fit_func and then using an object label to decide which of the n offsets needs to be added to the general function, except that I can't figure out how to pass the label.

```
def fit_func(x, g, offsets, lab):
    y1 = g[0] * cos(2*(x - g[1])) + offsets['lab',0] + g[2]
    y2 = g[0] * sin(2*(x - g[1])) + offsets['lab',1] + g[2]
    return [y1, y2]
```

The problem is that lab is not a float to be fit, so I can't figure out how to pass it. From reading some other threads I believe I will need a wrapper function, but I can't figure out what form it should take, and then how to call it in such a way that I can specify sigma and p0.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** I managed to produce a function that I thought would work. It used a global parameter call to choose options within the function call. So, for example I interleaved the y1 and y2 arrays, and had the function call the second equation every second run with a global getEven() and setEven(bool) call. However curve_fit really didn't like that. The fit values were nonsensical.

At the moment I am fitting the equation for y1 and the equation for y2 separately and taking the rms to determine g0 and g1 (this also gives me offsets['A',0] and offsets['A',1] respectively. I could just do this multiple times with each different object in the set, but I can't fit the g2 parameter this way, since in any given call to the y1 or y2 function it is degenerate with the corresponding offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example code that fits two different equations with a shared parameter using 'A' or 'B' decoding. It appears to work as you need for decoding the lab type, but I personally have never done this before and while it appears to function per your post the "text-to-float" conversion inside the function seems klunky to me. But it works.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# single array with all "X" data to pass around
num = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0])
ids = numpy.array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'])
xdata = numpy.array([num, ids]) # combine data, numpy auto-converts to 'text' type

# ydata is numeric single array
ydata = [9.0,8.0,7.0,6.0,4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0]


def fitFunction(data, commonParameter, pA, pB):
    numericDataAsText = data[0]
    textData = data[1]
    returnArray = []    
    for i in range(len(textData)):
        x = float(numericDataAsText[i])
        if textData[i] == 'A':
            val = commonParameter + x * pA
        elif textData[i] == 'B':
            val = commonParameter + x * pB
        else:
            raise(Exception('Error: must use A or B'))
        returnArray.append(val)
    return returnArray


initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

# curve fit the equations individually to their respective data
params, pcov = curve_fit(fitFunction, xdata, ydata, initialParameters)

# values for display of fitted function
commonParameter, pA, pB = params

# for plotting the fitting results
y_fit = fitFunction(xdata, commonParameter, pA, pB)

plt.plot(xdata[0], ydata, 'D') # plot the raw data as a scatterplot
plt.plot(xdata[0][:4], y_fit[:4])
plt.plot(xdata[0][4:], y_fit[4:])
plt.show()

print('fittedparameters:', params)
```

Comment: Thanks for fleshing out my suggestion!  I think it is a little bit of a hack, but if one is stuck with `curve_fit`, it is the only workaround.

Comment: I will carefully consider your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to show a more complete example of what you are trying, including the call to `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.   But, if I understand the question correctly, you want to have an argument for your model function that is *not* treated as a variable in the fit.  I believe that `curve_fit` cannot do this, and treats all arguments after the first as variables.

In fact, I think that your model function will not work for `curve_fit` because you expect `g` to be a sequence of values.  With `curve_fit`, each argument after the first will get a single float value.  So you probably want something like

```
def func(x, g0, g1, g2, offsets):
    y1 = g0 * cos(2*(x - g1)) + offsets['lab', 0] + g2
    ...
```

Anyway, I have two suggestions to work around this limitation of `curve_fit`:

First, you could overload `x`.  Now, `curve_fit` will internally apply `numpy.asarray()` to the `x` you pass in, but it will otherwise just pass it along to your model function.  So, if you turn `x` into a list containing your real `x` and your `lab`, you should be able to unpack this in your model function, say like

```
xhack = [x, offsets]
def func(x, g0, g1, g2):
    x, offsets = x
    ....

out = curve_fit(func, xhack, ...)
```

Personally, I think that's kind of ugly, but it might work.

Second, you could use lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/), which provides a higher level interface to curve fitting and fixes many of the shortcomings of `curve_fit`.  For your question in particular, lmfit's `Model` class for curve fitting examines the model function more carefully to turn function arguments into fitting parameters.  Specifically:

1. keyword arguments with non-numerical defaults will not be turned into fit parameters.
2. you can specify more than 1 "independent variable", and they do not have to be the first argument of the function.

That is, you could either write:

```
from lmfit import Model
def func(x, g0, g1, g2, offsets=None):
    y1 = g0 * cos(2*(x - g1)) + offsets['lab', 0] + g2

mymodel = Model(func)
```

or explicitly tell `Model` what the independent variables are:

```
from lmfit import Model
def func(x, g0, g1, g2, offsets):
    y1 = g0 * cos(2*(x - g1)) + offsets['lab', 0] + g2

mymodel = Model(func, independent_vars=['x', 'offsets'])
```

Either way, `offsets` can be any complex objects, and you would use this `mymodel` for curve fitting with:

```
# create parameter objects for this model, with initial values:
params = mymodel.make_params(g0=0, g1=0.5, g2=2.0)

# run the fit
result = mymodel.fit(ydata, params, x=x, offsets=offsets)
```

There are lots of other conveniences we added to lmfit (I am one of the developers) for building curve fitting models and working with parameters as high-level objects, but this might be enough to get you started.